# Override gstbasesrc.h/.c and gstpushsrc.h/.c

Tags: gstreamer

I've written a source plugin, and I want to do multi-stream with it, say, I want to create 3 srcpads inside my plugin. However, GstBaseSrcClass defines that there could be only ONE srcpad in the subclass, which is not what I expected. Therefore I decided to overide GstBaseSrc and GstPushSrc. For your information, is it possible to achieve? I would be obliged to take your advice! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked for example implementation of souphttpsrc? it has one src pad but when decoded you get two streams out of that, I wonder if there is at least one source element which has more than one pad.. I think I never used anything like that..

Even in case of rtspsrc which say in docs you can have multiple src pads (with template stream_%u) its really a Bin comprised of multiple udpsrc or so..

So you can make your plugin a bin exactly as in rtspsrc case and make another class (internal) - say MySingleSrc - which will produce the one src stream.. and you will have multiple instances of the MySingleSrc..

Internaly you can have one data object from which you will duplicate (memcpy) content to the multiple instances of MySingleSrc.

```
struct _GstRTSPSrcClass {
  GstBinClass parent_class;
};
```

[image: Rtspsrc bin]

UPDATE - what is the diagram:

The diagram shows the beginnning of the pipeline scheme - each box is an element - the red ones are UDP src's I just wanted to show you that there is no signe src with multiple src pads but rather the rspsrc is a bin which contains multiple signle-padded src elements in it.. and I propose you do the same - you can check the code of the rtspsrc in [cgit](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/gst/rtsp/gstrtspsrc.h?h=1.8).

This is about dot graphs and how to generate them - its very helpfull when debugging something: https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_generate_a_Gstreamer_pipeline_diagram_(graph)

But please take advice also from IRC of GStreamer.. I may be wrong.

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you help to explain the figure you attached? Thanks